# Java android session variable

Tags: java, android, android-room

I try do this.

in my table i have a row lp and I try do this :

```
@Query("set @i = 0; SELECT @i:=@i+1, ad.* * FROM added_note ad where order_id = :order_id and commission_id = 0")
LiveData<List<NoteEntity>> findNotesByOrder(long order_id);
```

but it does not work . When I try build my app is not work and not compile. I see a error

And this is my error :

```
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:98)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:25)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalResultStoringDecorator.execute(IncrementalResultStoringDecorator.java:41)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalResultStoringDecorator.execute(IncrementalResultStoringDecorator.java:27)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalAnnotationProcessingCompiler.execute(IncrementalAnnotationProcessingCompiler.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalAnnotationProcessingCompiler.execute(IncrementalAnnotationProcessingCompiler.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performCompilation(JavaCompile.java:156)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:126)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidJavaCompile.compile(AndroidJavaCompile.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor803.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at
```

Comment: What's not working? Did you get an error?

Comment: @grrigore is not compiling

Comment: So there is an error. What does it say?

Comment: @grrigore I edit my post

Comment: @grrigore an error is error: Must have exactly 1 query in @ Query value

Answer (score 0):

I believe the message is saying that you have a **';'** (semi-colon) and therefore that you are attempting to run 2 queries. You cannot.

However, the part before the SELECT i.e. `set @i = 0;`, if the semi-colon were removed would then result in a failure (unless this is some feature that I've not come accross). It appears to be the SET part of an SQLite UPDATE statement, if so it is invalid SQLite. As it would only be a guess to suggest the entire query no fix has been suggested.